# Warning : date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in

Tags: php

I receive these errors Please help me

> Warning
>   : date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in
>   on line
>   72
>
> Fatal error
>   : Uncaught Error: Call to a member function `format()` on boolean in ___ Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   on line
>   73

here's my code

[image: it is the code pic]

Comment: Post code, not screenshots of code. We can't run an image.

Answer (score 1):

date_create() is failing to create a date and it is returning FALSE rather than a DateTimeInterface. Hence the error, `expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given`. Double check your posted value to see that it is usable.

date_diff() returns false and causes the next error.