# How to get different day from date array

Tags: php

i have code like this

```
$awal  = date_create('$value[tgl_kembali]');
$akhir = date_create(); // waktu sekarang
$diff  = date_diff($awal, $akhir); 
echo 'Total selisih hari : ' . $diff->days;
```

with this code, i want to get different days form variable `$awal` which is data is array with `$akhir`, and i have error like this :

```
Warning: date_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Travel.remove\Travel\admin\pesanan.php on line 54

Notice: Trying to get property 'days' of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\Travel.remove\Travel\admin\pesanan.php on line 55
```

Comment: actually one of the date_create() calls returns FALSE due to unparseable date format and date_diff() expects a date object, most probably you should change first line to  $awal  = date_create($value['tgl_kembali']);

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning : date\_diff() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, boolean given in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50825680/warning-date-diff-expects-parameter-1-to-be-datetimeinterface-boolean-given)

Comment: ah i see, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php.net

source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

```
<?php
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days');
?>
111
```